# Graph theory (Graph Connectivity)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I'm studying graph theory and got stuck in one of the problems. It's about graph  connectivity with specific degree sequence condition. Please help me! [Number 3 in original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuUAc.jpg)

**My Try**: Vertex of degree $d_n$ and $d_n$ other vertices which is connected to it by $d_n$ edges form a connected graph of $d_n+1$ vertices. Then a vertice $d_{n-d_n-_1}$ should be also in a component that contains vertice of $d_n$ degree.(Since there are at most $n-d_n-1$ vertices.)
I don't know how to progress from here...

> **Q**: Suppose $G$ is simple with degree sequence $d_1\le d_2\le \cdots d_n$, and for $k\le n-d_n-1, d_k\ge k$. Show $G$ is connected.

Comment: Please *type* the problem you have problems with

Comment: How can I type it? I really don't know anything about it.

Comment: 1) You haven't understood what @Hagen von Eitzen wanted to say: we prefer not having a copy of the exercise, but something that is entirely (TeX-)written by you. 2) You don't show any effort: we answer to questions where we find " I have tried such and such..."

Comment: He means write it out instead of giving us a picture. There is a brief reference guide [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What was your attempt @Kim

Comment: I posted my attempt. Please check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at some values of $n$ and $d_n$ and see what is feasible. Note that if $d_n=n-1$ the graph is connected anyway. The threshold value calculated here, $n-d_n-1$, gives the minimum value for $d_1$ according to the problem statement.

$$\begin {array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
n & d_n & n-d_n-1 & ?\\ \hline
2 & 0 & 1 & \times\\ \hline
3 & 1 & 1 & \text{all degree 1 }\times\\ \hline
4 & 1 & 2 & \times\\ \hline
4 & 2 & 1 & \text{connected [1]}\\ \hline
\ge 4 & n-2 & 1 & \text{connected [1]}\\ \hline
 \end{array}$$

- Note [1] - when $d_n=n\!-\!2 \ (n\ge 4)$, the highest-degree node connects to all nodes except one; however the minimum degree is $1$ so that node must also connect to one of the other nodes $\to$ connected.

This gives us our clue as to why the conditions given force a connected graph. Given a maximum degree of $n-a$ leaves $a-1$ nodes not directly connected to the maximum degree node, $v_m$. However the threshold degree imposed means that each of these nodes must have degree of at least $n-(n-a)-1 = a-1$, so they must also connect to at least one of the nodes connected to $v_m$. Hence the graph is connected and has [diameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) of at most $4$.