# Graph Theory (Connectivity)

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Suppose  *G* is simple with degree sequence $d_1 \leq d_2\leq ....\leq d_n$, and for $k \leq n-d_n-1$, $d_k \geq k$. Show G is connected.

I posted this question before, and got an answer, but I couldn't understand it fully. (Especially about why $d_1 \geq n-d_n-1$.) Here's a link to that answer. [Graph theory (Graph Connectivity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052344/graph-theory-graph-connectivity)    Anybody, help me, please.

Comment: So, every time the put your question on hold, you're going to repost it ?!?!?!

Comment: Please make this more specific problem statement ("why $d_1 \ge n - d_n -1$") an edit into your earlier Question (now on hold, awaiting your additional context).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate, but voting to reopen the other. It seems that sufficient context *has* been added there.